# Is it feasible to join the below query as one query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can the following queries be combined into a single query?

1.

```
select a.usr_id, a.usr_desc as ,a.usr_type,b.usr_desc as usr_prof_name 
from sc_usr_prof_m a, sc_usr_type_m b 
where a.usr_type=b.usr_type 
and a.current_status='A' 
order by a.usr_id;
```

2.

```
select distinct a.usr_id,a.usr_desc,b.dept_name 
from sc_usr_prof_m a ,sc_user_depts b 
where a.usr_id=b.usr_id 
and a.usr_status='E'  
and a.current_status='A';
```

3.

```
select a.usr_id,a.usr_desc,b.curr_code,b.min_amt,b.max_amt 
from sc_usr_prof_m a, sc_auth_limit_m b  
where a.usr_id=b.usr_id 
and a.usr_status='E'
and a.current_status='A' 
and b.max_amt not in ('0') 
order by b.usr_id;
```

4.

```
select a.usr_id,a.usr_desc,b.msg_type 
from sc_usr_prof_m a, sc_user_msgs_m b  
where a.usr_id=b.usr_id 
and a.usr_status='E' 
and a.current_status='A' 
and b.swift_enable='Y' 
order by a.usr_id;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I formatted your queries and added a simple question to the body based off of your title, but you should add more content to your actual post. It would also help if you gave an example of your table structures, some sample data, and a sample of what you would expect your result dataset to look like. Please take some time to read through the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Feasible, yes. Sensible, probably not. The first query filters a different set of records from  `sc_usr_prof_m`, so combining it with the other queries changes the result set. Each query joins to different tables which presumably have no common join columns  beyond `usr_id` so that would generate a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structures it would be difficult to say precisely which way would give you the best results. You *could* rewrite the queries into one, joining the various tables together, but there seems to be quite a disparate selection of tables you are selecting from. Without knowing your table designs it would be difficult to say if that is the best course of action.

Alternatively, if you are simply looking to combine the result-sets into a single dataset, basically merging the results from each query into a single output, then you could use `UNION [ALL]`. You would need to ensure that the columns in the select list of each of your queries are matched/aligned properly. This isn't ideal, but it should give you what you want.

```
with combined_results as (
    select a.usr_id as usr_id, 
        a.usr_desc as usr_desc, 
        a.usr_type as usr_type, 
        b.usr_desc as usr_prof_name,
        null as dept_name, 
        null as cur_code,
        0 as min_amt,
        0 as max_amt,
        null as msg_type
    from sc_usr_prof_m a, sc_usr_type_m b 
    where a.usr_type=b.usr_type 
    and a.current_status='A' 
    union all
    select distinct 
        a.usr_id as usr_id, 
        a.usr_desc as usr_desc,
        null as usr_type,
        null as usr_prof_name, 
        b.dept_name as dept_name, 
        null as cur_code,
        0 as min_amt,
        0 as max_amt,
        null as msg_type
    from sc_usr_prof_m a ,sc_user_depts b 
    where a.usr_id=b.usr_id 
    and a.usr_status='E'  
    and a.current_status='A'
    union all
    select a.usr_id as usr_id, 
        a.usr_desc as usr_desc, 
        null as usr_type,
        null as usr_prof_name, 
        null as dept_name,
        b.curr_code as curr_code, 
        b.min_amt as min_amt, 
        b.max_amt as max_amt,
        null as msg_type
    from sc_usr_prof_m a, sc_auth_limit_m b  
    where a.usr_id=b.usr_id 
    and a.usr_status='E'
    and a.current_status='A' 
    and b.max_amt not in ('0') 
    union all
    select a.usr_id as usr_id, 
        a.usr_desc as usr_desc, 
        null as usr_type,
        null as usr_prof_name, 
        null as dept_name,
        null as cur_code,
        0 as min_amt,
        0 as max_amt,
        b.msg_type as msg_type 
    from sc_usr_prof_m a, sc_user_msgs_m b  
    where a.usr_id=b.usr_id 
    and a.usr_status='E' 
    and a.current_status='A' 
    and b.swift_enable='Y'
)
select *
from combined_results 
order by usr_id;
```

I would also suggest that you write out your joins:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4
from my_a_table a
join my_b_table b
on b.col1 = a.col1
where a.col1 = 123;
```

Instead of how you are currently doing it:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4
from my_a_table a, my_b_table b
where b.col1 = a.col1
and a.col1 = 123;
```

If for no other reason than readability, especially in larger queries with multiple joins.

Comment: HELP ME OUT THIS